# how to utf-8 encode the file name with uploading the file content in multi part post

Tags: file-upload, encoding, utf-8, httpurlconnection, multipartform-data

Having uploading file working fine except when the file name is double byte.

The code snippet below shows a possible place to do the file name encoding, but not sure if it is right, or where is the right place to apply "charset=utf-8". Any help is appreciated.

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String urlString = WebApiConstants.getInstance().getBaseURL();
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "--BoundaryStringUsingCurrentTime”+currentTimeMillis();

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    try {
      URL url = new URL(urlString);
      connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);
      connection.setUseCaches(false);

      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

      List<BasicNameValuePair> headers = getHeaderNameValuePairs();

      for (BasicNameValuePair hdr : headers) {
          connection.setRequestProperty(hdr.getName(), hdr.getValue());
      }

      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
      outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
      outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

      outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"requests\"" + lineEnd);
      outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/json" + lineEnd + lineEnd);                       
                outputStream.writeBytes(getJsonDataString(attachment.getMessageId()));
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd + twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

      /* ???
      // could encode the fail name and put in, not sure if it is right? 
      String fileNameUtf8 = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
      outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file0\";filename=\""
                   + fileNameUtf8 + "\"" + lineEnd);

      */

      outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file0\";filename=\""
                   + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

      outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + mimeType + lineEnd + lineEnd);
      FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToFile));
      bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
      bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
      buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

      bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
      while (bytesRead > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
      }

      outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
      outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                … … …
                … … …
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the filename like this:

```java
final private static String hexStr = "0123456789ABCDEF";

private static String MimeEncodeQP(String s)
{
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(12 + (bytes.length * 3));
    output.append("=?UTF-8?Q?");

    for ( final byte b : bytes )
    {
        if( b == 32 )
        {
            output.append('_');
        }
        else if( ((b >= 33) && (b <= 60)) ||
                 ((b >= 62) && (b <= 126)) )
        {
            output.append((char) b);
        }
        else
        {
            output.append('=')
                  .append(hexStr.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4)
                  .append(hexStr.charAt(b & 0x0F));
        }
    }

    output.append("?=");

    return output.toString();
}
```

```java
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file0\";filename=\"" + MimeEncodeQP(fileName) + "\"" + lineEnd);
```

Read the following specs for more details:

[RFC 2045 "Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) Part One: Format of Internet Message Bodies", Section 67 "Quoted-Printable Content-Transfer-Encoding"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7)

[RFC 2047 "MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) Part Three: Message Header Extensions for Non-ASCII Text"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047)

[RFC 7578 "Returning Values from Forms: multipart/form-data"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578), Section 5.1 "Non-ASCII Field Names and Values".

[HTML4, Section 17.13.4.2 "multipart/form-data"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

[HTML5, Section 4.10.22.7 "Multipart form data"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#multipart-form-data)

Comment: Thanks Remy.I think String fileNameUtf8 = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
      outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file0\";filename=\""
                   + fileNameUtf8 + "\"" + lineEnd); is simpler and works as well.

Comment: It may be simpler, but it is also the **WRONG** encoding scheme for this situation. `Content-Disposition` is a MIME-defined header (see [RFC 2183](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2183)). The various specs I linked to in my answer specifically state that MIME encoding is required for the filename. URL encoding uses `%` instead of `=` to indicate hex values, and URL encoding uses different rules for encoding reserved characters and whitespace. So *DO NOT* use `URLEncoder` to encode the filename. That is not what webservers are expecting in `multipart/form-data` posts.

Comment: Your own question said that you were "*not sure if it is right*" regarding the way you were using `URLEncoder` to encode the filename.  MIME encoding is the correct way, not URL encoding.

Comment: Thanks Remy for the explanation. Tried with your way, however it does not work in server side (but works if client encoded it by using URLEncoder.encode. Maybe the server has implementation to expect something in some way? I was wondering if there is a place in the higher level of the posted data package to specify the data needs to be utf-8 encoded, and the HttpURLConnection some how could take care of the encoding automatically. Looks like it has to be encoded before give to the "Content-Disposition".

Comment: What I showed is the *correct* way to encode a filename in a `Content-Disposition` header. It is a self-contained header, there is nowhere else to specify encoding. If the server is not accepting it, then the server is broken. Either its decoder has a bug, or it does not implement RFC2047 to begin with. So this is a server-side problem. Your client must use MIME-encoding, not URL-encoding. Period. That is a fact, not debatable. Read the specs I linked to, they are very clear on this matter. You should tell the server admins that their server is broken and let them fix it on their end.